# Running Matlab with Gnome-Do: bash script problem

Tags: bash, gnome-do, matlab

In Ubuntu, Matlab should be started with the following command: `setsid matlab -desktop`

Accordingly, I've created such a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid matlab -desktop
```

and saved it as /usr/bin/launchMatlab.

Now, if I press Alt+F2, type launchMatlab and click Run or press Enter, Matlab is started. However, Gnome Do, though finds the script, only allows to open, reveal, open terminal and copy to clipboard. Execution of the script as a program is allowed.

How to make Do launch the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a launcher (.desktop file). To do this, right click on your desktop and click 'Create Launcher...' and fill in the details:

[image: matlab.desktop]

You can then copy it to `~/.local/share/applications` and you should be able to type 'Matlab' to open it with gnome-do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/launchMatlab
```

On a side-note, it's better to put custom commands in /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin. Let the package manager rule over /usr/bin.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/launchMatlab /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: The script is executable: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35 2011-06-24 11:30 /usr/bin/launchMatlab