# How to make gnome-do recognize a specific application

Tags: gnome-do

I have installed an application. But it is not recognized by gnome-do and I have to run it every time from terminal. I am using xubuntu14.10.

Comment: What is that application?

Comment: matlab. actually I haven't installed it. I just  extracted it and I want to run it via gnome-do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do knows applications by their `.desktop` file. It searches the standard desktop file paths - `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` are generally the two main ones, but there are others. In order to get an application to appear in Do it needs a `.desktop` file somewhere in the standard desktop paths.

It turns out that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52408/running-matlab-with-gnome-do-bash-script-problem/52448#52448) is about how to create a `.desktop` file for matlab. :)